# Reshaping Pandas dataframe for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have what is (to me at least) a complicated dataframe I'm trying to reshape so that I can more easily create visualizations. The data is from a survey and each row is a complete survey with 247 columns. These columns are split as to what sort of data they contain. Some is identifying information, (who took the survey, what product the survey is on, what the scores were on particular questions and what comments they had about that particular product). Here is a simplification of the dataframe

```
   id    Evaluator     item    Mar1   Mar1[Comments]    Comf1  Comf1[Com..
   1         001       11       3      "asf adfsfs.."     3    "text.."
   2         001       14       2      "asf adfsfs.."     4    "text.."
   3         002       11       4      "asf adfsfs.."     2    "text.."
   4         002       14       3      "asf adfsfs.."     3    "text.."
   5         002       34       0      "asf adfsfs.."     1    "text.."
   6         003       11       2      "asf adfsfs.."     0    "text.."
   ....
```

It continues on from here, but in this case 'Mar1' and 'Comf1' are rated questions. I have another datatable that helps describe all the question and question types within the survey so I can perform data selections like the following...

```
df[df['ItemNum']==11][(qtable[(qtable['type'].str.contains("OtoU")==True)]).id]
```

Which pulls from qtable all the 'types' of 'OtoU' (all the rating questions) for the ItemNum 11. This is all well and good and gets me something like this...

```
Mar1   Mar2  Comf1  Comf2  Comf3  Interop1  Interop2  .....
 1      2      3      1      3        4         4
 2      3      3      2      4        2         2
 2      1      1      4      4        1         2
 1      3      2      2      2        1         1
 3      4      1      2      3        3         3
```

I can't really do much with it in that form (at least I don't think I can). What I 'think' I need to do is flatten it out into a form that goes more like

```
Item  Question   Score  Section    Evaluator  ...
 11     Mar1       3    Maritime      001     ...
 11     Comf1      2    Comfort       001     ...
 11     Comf2      3    Comfort       001     ...
 14     Mar1       1    Maritime      001     ...
```

But, I'll be damned if I know how to do that. I tried to do it (the wrong way I'm pretty sure) with iterating through the dataframe but I quickly realized that it both took quiet some time to do, and the resulting data was of questionable integrity.

So, (very) long story short. How do I go about doing this sort of transform through the power of pandas? I would like to do a number of plots including box plots by question for each 'item' as well as factorplots broken by 'section' and multi line charts plotting the mean of each question by item... if that helps you better understand where I am trying to go with this thing. Sorry for the long post, I just wanted to make sure I supplied enough information to get a solid answer.

Thanks,